# Shiny app for Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: r, shiny, montecarlo

I am trying to build a Shiny app in R for Monte Carlo Simulation. So I want to forecast revenue for a firm which is dependent on 4 variables, A,B,C,D.
I want user to input the min and max value for these variables, generate uniform random numbers on the basis of those values and hence calculate revenue.

Please find below the code I am using-

ui.R

```
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

      # Application title
      headerPanel("Sales Forecasting using Simulation"),

      sidebarPanel("Input the below values-",
        numericInput("num1", "Min No of A:",100),
        numericInput("num2", "Max No of A:",1000),
        numericInput("num3", "Min B:",49),
        numericInput("num4", "Max B:",99),
        numericInput("num5", "Min C:",2000),
        numericInput("num6", "Max C:",5000),
        numericInput("num7", "Min D:",10),
        numericInput("num8", "Max D:",20)
        ),

      mainPanel("",
                h1("Results for Monte Carlo Simulation"),
                tabsetPanel(
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("distPlot")), 
                  tabPanel("Summary",  htmlOutput("mytable"))

    ))

    ))
```

Server.R

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      getAFYP_round <- reactive({
        set.seed=12345
        options(scipen = 999)
        AA<-runif(10000, input$num1, input$num2)
        BB<-runif(10000, input$num3, input$num4)
        CC<-runif(10000, input$num5, input$num6)
        DD<-runif(10000, input$num7, input$num8)

        AFYP <- AA*BB*CC*DD

        AFYP_round=round(AFYP, digits = -7)
        AFYP_round
      })

      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        options(scipen = 999)
        AFYP_round<-getAFYP_round() 
        zz<-as.data.frame(AFYP_round)
        Freqa=as.data.frame(prop.table(table(AFYP_round)))
        library(dplyr)
        Freqa=Freqa %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Freq))
        library(ggplot2)
        ggplot(Freqa, aes(x=AFYP_round, y=Freq)) +         geom_bar(stat='identity',col="red", fill="yellow") + labs(title="Histogram for Simulation")+labs(x="AFYP", y="Freq")

      })

      output$mytable <- renderUI({
        options(scipen = 999)
        AFYP<-getAFYP_round()
        c1 <- c("Mean", mean(AFYP))
        c2 <- c("Std Dev", sd(AFYP))
        c3 <- c("Minimum", min(AFYP))
        c4 <- c("Maximum", max(AFYP))
        c5 <- c("Maximum", median(AFYP)) 
        c6 <- c("Q(.25)", quantile(AFYP,0.25)) 
        c7 <- c("Q(.75)", quantile(AFYP,0.75))
        c8 <- c("Q(.05)", quantile(AFYP,0.05))
        c9 <- c("Q(.95)", quantile(AFYP,0.95))
        c10 <- c("Q(.025)", quantile(AFYP,0.025))
        c11 <- c("Q(.975)", quantile(AFYP,0.975))

        Summary=rbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11)
        ab<-as.data.frame(Summary)
        names(ab)[names(ab)=="V1"] <- "Measures"
        names(ab)[names(ab)=="25%"] <- "Value"
        output$ac <- renderDataTable(ab,options = list(paging = FALSE,searching = FALSE))
        dataTableOutput("ac")

      })

    })
```

So, I have the following problems with the code:

1. I am only able to generate random uniform numbers for AA and BB. CC and DD are not generated and R does not throw any error.
2. I want to generate a histogram with the freq of AFYP_round. But R seems to take that variable as continuous rather than discrete.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I made some `print()` in your code and CC and DD are generated.

Comment: @ChristopheD. where are you placing print()?

Comment: Just after the `CC<-` and `DD<-`

Comment: True. But it is not being used in the AFYP formula after that. Or the vector for CC and DD is getting generated.

Comment: CC and DD are used i tried to print `mean(round(AA*BB,digits=-7))` `mean(round(AA*BB*CC,digits=-7))` and `mean(round(AA*BB*CC*DD,digits=-7))` and the results are `[1] 0
[1] 142093000
[1] 2127709000` I think i dont understand the problem you see

Comment: When I use these formulas, I get the error-  Error in mean(round(AA * BB * CC, digits = -7)) : 
  object 'CC' not found

Comment: @ChristopheD. Hey what version of R are you using?

Comment: R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)